# How to get label on button click in tableview cell for prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, segue

I have a tableview. i need to get the label "usernameLabel" from that cell and assign a variable to them. I need to pass that variable to prepareForSegue. **The problem is the label is the wrong label from the wrong cell.**

here is what i have:

```
var username: String!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

    username = usernameLabel.text
    cell.button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapLabel(_:)))
    cell.button.addGestureRecognizer(tapButton)

    return cell as MainCell
}

func tapButton(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewToView2Segue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ViewToView2Segue" {
            let userProfileViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
            secondViewController.usernamePassed = usernamePassed
        }
}
```

***simplified question:*** i need to pass the label.text to another view controller via segue. but currently, it is getting the label from the wrong cell.

Comment: `username = usernameLabel.text` is `usernameLabel` per cell? If so you'll need `cell.usernameLabel.text`. But what are you trying to do? You need to pass the content from the label, is that correct?

Comment: @SeanWang i need to pass the label.text to another view controller via segue. but currently, it is getting the label from the wrong cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method will be multiple times so assigning value in that method will not work, also why are you using `tapGesture` on button instead of adding action to button, try to change your `cellForRowAtIndex` like this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell
    cell.button.setTitle( usernameLabel.text, forState: .Normal)
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Now add this `buttonAction` function inside your `ViewController`

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let center = sender.center
    let point = sender.superview!.convertPoint(center, toView:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MainCell //Add superview on the basis of your button hierarchy in the cell
    username =  cell.usernameLabel.text
    print(username)  
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewToView2Segue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Your code that uses `sender.superview!.superview!` is fragile. It relies on the current layout of the cell. If you move the button inside a new parent view, for example, then this code would break. Better to use the button's bounds, converted from it's coordinate space to the table view's coordinate space, and ask the table view which cell contains that button. The code I have for this is in Objective-C or I'd post it as a separate answer.

Comment: This is the error I get: `-[UITapGestureRecognizer superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Check the edited answer. also use add target remove the tapgesture code.

Comment: what is `buttonCenter`?

Comment: I get this error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'`

Comment: on which line ? Also put break point on indexPath and check you are getting indexPath or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120921/discussion-between-johnniexo88-and-ndoc).

Comment: any suggestion or fixes?

Comment: The code is working perfectly for me, I have try with running on xcode, Also use `!` after `sender.superview!` like this.

Comment: wow youre the best! thank u so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not save state data in cells. You should have the info that you want in your model (probably an array). When the user taps a cell you should use the indexPath of the selected cell to fetch the info from the model, not from a label on the cell.

(Look up the MVC design pattern for background. A table view cell is  a view object, and should not store data. That's the model's job.)

Comment: Nice you removed the paragraph about what a mess it is.

Comment: I realized that I misunderstood the code I was reading at first glance, so part of that paragraph was incorrect. The code is still a mess though.

Comment: what would be an example of the model file?